# How is a type that's forward declared in a function parameter list visible outside the function scope?

Tags: c++, scope, language-lawyer, declaration, function-parameter

The following program compiles, which I find strange.

```
void f(class s);
using u = s;      // ok, but why?
```

`s` is a forward declaration of a class inside a function parameter list, and it seems to me it should not be visible outside the function scope.

[basic.scope.param](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.param) seems the obvious place I would find this rule, but I can't work it out. The wording could be somewhere in [dcl.dcl](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl), but I'm not sure where to look.

What rule covers this? Optionally, an explanation of *why* this rule exists would be nice.

Comment: The parameter and its type are two separate things, and there are separate rules that apply to both. The parameter itself is visible only inside its function. Here `class s` is a type, and the parameter is unnamed, same as `void f(int)` declares a function with a single `int` parameter that's unnamed. Here you have a forward declaration and the question here becomes what is the rule that governs where a forward declaration is visible.

Comment: `void f(class s)` is a declaration, not a definition.    It declares (and does not *define*) both a type `s` and a function that accepts that type `s` as an argument - and both are within the containing scope.   It is not possible to *define* the function in that way unless `s` has been previously defined in that compilation unit.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, you're right. The analogy with `n` doesn't really make sense, since it's a different kind of entity than `s`. I'll edit that out, and also mention the forward declaration aspect.

Comment: I found the following in `class.name`: "A declaration consisting solely of class-key identifier ; is either a redeclaration of the name in the current scope or a forward declaration of the identifier as a class name. It introduces the class name into the current scope." I think that some digging into the definition of "current scope", and whether the parameter declaration's "current scope" is the same as the function body's "current scope" (it's obviously not), will produce an authoritative answer.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yeah, this is a dupe. I'm not sure why I couldn't find it, but using "elaborated type specifier" while searching showed the target right away. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, this rule is not particularly new. It existed since C++'s inception, pretty much. As for C++20, it is written as follows:

> **[basic.scope.pdecl]**
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.scope.pdecl#7) The point of declaration of a class first declared in an elaborated-type-specifier is as follows:
>
> - ...
> - for an elaborated-type-specifier of the form
>
>   ```
>   class-key identifier
>   ```
>
>   if the elaborated-type-specifier is used in the decl-specifier-seq or parameter-declaration-clause of a function defined in namespace scope, the identifier is declared as a class-name in the namespace that contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration.

But you are looking in the latest greatest draft head. You can't find it because the  draft has [P1787](http://wg21.link/P1787) merged in. It changes the normative wording and moves it with the intent of fixing some outstanding wording issues and improving the standard's approach in a world where modules exist.

Today, the relevant part resides in

> **[dcl.type.elab]**
>
> [3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#3) Otherwise, an elaborated-type-specifier E shall not have an attribute-specifier-seq. If E contains an identifier but no nested-name-specifier and (unqualified) lookup for the identifier finds nothing, E shall not be introduced by the enum keyword and declares the identifier as a class-name. The target scope of E is the nearest enclosing namespace or block scope.

And essentially, it means the same thing the C++20 wording does. It introduces the the class name as if by forward declaration into the nearest enclosing scope.

---

As for why this rule exists. Well... it doesn't exist in C up to date. Which creates some fairly obscure problems for the uninitiated. Consider this simple program:

```
void func(struct foo*);

struct foo { int bar; };

int main() {
  struct foo f;
  func(&f);
}

void func(struct foo* pf) {
  pf->bar = 0;
}
```

It produces a [slew of diagnostics](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:12),source:%27void+func(struct+foo*)%3B%0A%0Astruct+foo+%7B+int+bar%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++struct+foo+f%3B%0A++func(%26f)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+func(struct+foo*+pf)+%7B%0A++pf-%3Ebar+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg111,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc17+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:17.425431711145997,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+11.1%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:82.574568288854,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), which frankly don't seem justified. IMHO it's a shortcoming of C, which in turn is motivation enough for C++ to do things the way it does. Compile the exact same program with a C++ compiler, and it's [well formed](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:12),source:%27void+func(struct+foo*)%3B%0A%0Astruct+foo+%7B+int+bar%3B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++struct+foo+f%3B%0A++func(%26f)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+func(struct+foo*+pf)+%7B%0A++pf-%3Ebar+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:17.425431711145997,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+11.1%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:82.574568288854,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: Thanks. This wording is exactly what I was looking for. Do you happen to know where the wording got moved to in the draft head? I'll search for it myself, as well.

Comment: @cigien - Yeah, I'm just editing it in. It's one sentence in a sea of text.

Comment: It turns out this is a dupe; I guess I wasn't searching for the right terms. The answer there is quite outdated though, so it might make sense to add this answer on the target.

Answer (score 0):

`class s` is a forward declaration. That is equivalent to

```
class s;
void f(s);
```

`s` is not the name of a variable, but it's a type. So you are just saying that function `f` takes a parameter of type `s`.
Also the next line tells that `u` is equivalent to `s`. No problem. You don't need the full definition to do that.

Comment: The question doesn't deal with whether `f` is defined at all. I could define it, and `s` would still be visible outside. You're right that your code seems to be "equivalent" to that in the question, but this is a language-lawyer question. I'm looking for references from the standard to justify this. Also, I've removed the comparison with a variable name from the question.

Comment: @cigien Sorry, I was on the smartphone and missed the language-lawyer tag.